# how to make @symbol in string.xml for android

Tags: android, string, android-layout

I am trying to make @sancorporation in my android application. I have written strings in string.xml e.g "<"string  name="cor_name">sancorporation"<"/string>, but I need something like this "<"string  name="cor_name">@sancorporation"<"/string>. How to take special symbol in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ascii  value of @  symble is 0040 so try it

for @sancorporation

```
          <string name="mytest">&#64;sancorporation</string>

           or 
           <string name="mytest">\u0040 sancorporation</string>
```

Comment: \u00A9 is ANSII value of @ symble so you can use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

```
<string name="specialChar"> "@" </string>
```

You can also try this

```
<string name="specialChar"> \@ </string>
```

**Edit:**
Now I notice that you want to write @sanCorporation.

so you can use this in string.xml file:

```
<string name="corp"> "@sanCorp" </string>
```